# unknown call types when querying device call logs

Tags: android, calllog, xiaomi, oppo

In the snippet below, I am trying to read call logs and print their call type

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, ...);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    int callType = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.TYPE));
    Log.d("callType", callType);
}
```

In some cases, I get values not listed in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#TYPE). Does anyone know what these callTypes mean?

---

### callType `10`

COMIO:

- COMIO S1

OPPO:

- A37fw
- CPH1609
- CPH1701
- CPH1801
- CPH1803
- CPH1823
- CPH1853
- CPH1859
- CPH1881
- CPH1893
- CPH1909
- CPH1911
- CPH1945
- CPH1969
- CPH1989
- RMX1801
- RMX1807

Realme:

- RMX1825
- RMX1827
- RMX1833
- RMX1901
- RMX1911
- RMX1992

Xiaomi:

- Redmi 3S

---

### callType `20`

OPPO:

- CPH1609
- CPH1701
- CPH1803
- CPH1853
- CPH1859
- CPH1901
- CPH1909
- RMX1801
- RMX1807

Realme:

- RMX1825
- RMX1833
- RMX1901

---

### callType `100`

Realme:

- RMX1827
- RMX1901

---

### callType `1001`

PANASONIC:

- Panasonic P85 NXT

---

Comment: Hey, did you get any work around for this issue? i am also getting wrong type from realme device for outgoing 100, incoming 101 etc. strange is some time getting call log type same defined in the official document.

Comment: no positive developments so far. instead, I now have a few more unknown call type IDs: 10, 100, -20.

Comment: @RaRa did you find solution for this? we are also getting 100,101 for Realme. but what about missed call type?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I got 100 and 101 value. This happens last dialed call only

Comment: Did someone found any updates? Still getting it randomly for Vivo and Asus phones. But it reverted back to normal call type values after some time. Its not predictable. Anyone found the possible values for phones?

Comment: We get 100,101 in Vivo phones and 8,9 in Asus phones. And after some time values are back to usual constants 1,2,3. Why is this happening. is it possible to get original values from different columns of calllog table at these time?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to explain the following additional call type constants: 1000, 1001, 1002

In my case the call type constants above are used for IMS call statuses in the calllog table.

See here:
https://gerrit.aicp-rom.com/c/AICP/frameworks_base/+/57943/1/core/java/android/provider/CallLog.java#210

If possible, check the android source for the firmware you see the extra codes coming from in core/java/android/provider/CallLog.java. Hope this helps! It's unfortunate that this is not well-documented

Answer (score 0):

For my OnePlus device the following codes are for:

- **100 - VoWiFi Outgoing call**
- **101 - VoWiFi Incomming call**

So I can only assume that the other codes like 10/20 might be for the same purpose but for other manufacturers.
To bad that the codes are not documented and implemented in the android libs.